# Benefit to generating serial numbers of a constant length

Tags: radix

I am generating a serial number for a tracking system in base 36 (0-9, A-Z). Customers will be calling in with this number to inquire about relevant information associated with this serial number. Is there any benefit to ensuring that the length of the generated serial number is a constant?

Since this is a new project the current serial numbers that I am generating corresponding to a UID of a low value, such as 14. Therefore the generated serial number is:

`E`

Are there any benefits to producing a serial code with these length requirements?
Following are two examples of constant length generation methods.

Adding prefixed 0's:

`000000E`

Starting with a UID of a large value such that a length of, say 7, such that the first serial number generated is:

`1000000`

Comment: Why base-36? Why not base-10? Easier for the customer, and then certainly this issue does not arise.

Comment: @EJP The question would still arise. In base 10 I would still be curious if there would be a benefit to having all serial numbers a length of, say 7, versus the first 100 customers receiving serial numbers that are less than three digits in length. Base 36 in this case is better because the serial number should not be too long.